# Django query list to template - display items by category

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying to create an array to pass to the template page which should group my items based on its categories.

I don't know how to do it with a single query in Django so I though to define a function which should get the array similar to the result I would like to show

## My goal to display

```
Title: Category_A
|
|_Menu_item_1_in_cat_A
  |_option_1_of_menu_item_1
  |_option_2_of_menu_item_1
  |_extra_1_of_menu_item_1
|
|_Menu_item_2_in_cat_A
  |_option_1_of_menu_item_2

Title: Category_B
|
|_Menu_item_3_in_cat_B
  |_option_1_of_menu_item_3
  |_option_2_of_menu_item_3
  |_extra_1_of_menu_item_3
```

My function doesn't work... this is the result but there are items to display...

```
[{'category': 'Category A', 'items': {}, 'options': {}, 'extras': {}}, {'category': 'Category B', 'items': {}, 'options': {}, 'extras': {}}]
```

## Models.py

```py
class Owner
...

    def get_menu_list(self):
        menu_list = []
        # defining the categories
        categories = (
            Menu.objects.filter(owner=self.id)
            .order_by("category")
            .values("category")
            .distinct()
        )
        for category in categories:
            # create main group
            details = {}
            details["category"] = category["category"]

            # select the items present in the category
            items_list = []
            options_list = []
            extras_list = []
            for item in Menu.objects.filter(owner=self.id, category=category)
                items_list.append(item)
                # add options and extra to the category
                for item in MenuOptionItem.objects.get(menu=item.id)):
                    options_list.append(option)
                for extra in MenuExtraItem.objects.get(menu=item.id)):
                    extras_list.append(extra)
            details["items"] = items_list
            details["options"] = options_list
            details["extras"] = extrass_list

            menu_list.append(details)

        return menu_list


class Menu(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="menu_images/", blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

class MenuOptionItem(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class MenuExtraItem(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

## Views.py

```
    restaurant = Owner.objects.get(id=owner_id)

    return render(
        request,
        "detail_page.html",
        {
            "restaurant": owner,
        },
    )
```

## detail_page.html

```
{% for category, items in restaurant.get_menu_list %}
    ...
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item.name }}
        {% for option in item.options %}
            {{ option.name }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for extra in item.extras %}
            {{ extra.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what was wrong in my function

```
 # select the items present in the category
        details["items"] = Menu.objects.filter(
            restaurant=self.id, category=category["category"]
        )

        for item in Menu.objects.filter(
            restaurant=self.id, category=category["category"]
        ):
        details["options"] = MenuOptionItem.objects.filter(menu=item.id)
        details["ingredients"] = MealExtraItem.objects.filter(menu=item.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

to be honest I don't love the way you're building the dictionary. If you're okay with building it like this ...

then this will work

```
def getSubs(self, item):
    return {
        "options", MenuOptionItem.objects.get(menu=item.id),
        "extra", MenuExtraItem.Objects.get(menu=item.id)
    }
def getItem(self, category):
    return {item: getSubs(item) for item in Menu.objects.filter(owner=self.id, category=category)}

def get_menu_list(self):
    categories =Menu.objects.filter(owner=self.id).order_by("category").values("category").distinct()
    return {category: getItems(category) for category in categories}
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan, I'm new to Python/Django so I'm not familiar with it. In PHP I would have done in one single query and then listed the array. May I ask how would you suggest to do it?

Comment: Ohh I see. I think it would be best to pass just the menu to the template and put the work on the template side. You could do something like {% for category in categories %}...

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts but I'm still unable to solve my issue.. I'm too new to Django/Python and probably this is the most complex template render that I'm trying to create so far.. My issue is that I can't make to render the template properly with your suggestion...I cant call the object from views.py nor in template.py. I've added my goal, and my template.. hopefully it can be of help

Comment: I'm wondering if I shall add a `ManyToManyField` in `Menu` for linking `MenuOptionItem` and `MenuExtraItem`

Comment: yeah that was the other thing I was going to comment on. Hard to give you suggestions because I don't know exactly what you are trying to build but maybe you want to make a menu class then a category class where a menu has many categories and a category has many items. Item would then be a super class and OptionItem amd ExtraItem would inherit from item. With that setup your template would be pretty simple: for category in menu.category_set.all for item in category.item_set.all

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to create the array, I know it is not "good looking" and looks rather complex but it is the sole way that I've sort to make it to works. I slightly review my function which in theory seems correct to me but doesn't print any item